# Блокировка кнопок

Tags: javascript, json, foreach

```js
$("#proced").change(function() {
     var dat = [{
       "Time": "09:00",
       "Proced": "Санникова Александра",
     }, {
       "Time": "09:00",
       "Proced": "Лузанова Вера",
     }, {
       "Time": "11:30",
       "Proced": "Праведникова Валентина"
     }];



     dat.forEach(function(el) {

       var time = el["Time"].substr(0, 5);
       var proc = el["Proced"];

       var fam = document.getElementById('proced').value;



       if (fam == proc) {

         var elem = document.querySelector('[id="time-is-' + time + '"]')
         elem && elem.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
         elem.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
       }
      
     });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control input-sm" required name="Proced" id="proced" style="width:300px;">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Санникова Александра">Санникова Александра</option>
  <option value="Лузанова Вера">Лузанова Вера</option>
  <option value="Праведникова Валентина">Праведникова Валентина</option>
  <option value="Елена Чиркова">Елена Чиркова</option>
  <option value="Лебединская Ирина">Лебединская Ирина</option>

</select>
<section class="color-7" id="btn-click" style=" margin-top:45px ;">

  <p class="bb">


    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-09:00">09:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-09:30" onclick="">09:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-10:00" onclick="">10:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-10:30" onclick="">10:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-11:00" onclick="">11:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-11:30" onclick="">11:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-12:00" onclick="">12:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-12:30" onclick="">12:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-13:00" onclick="">13:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-13:30" onclick="">13:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-14:00" onclick="">14:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-14:30" onclick="">14:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-15:00" onclick="">15:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-15:30" onclick="">15:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-16:00" onclick="">16:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-16:30" onclick="">16:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-17:00" style="width:504px;" onclick="">17:00</button>

  </p>

</section>

</ul>
</span>
```

Как мне при смене значений select выделять и блокировать ту кнопку, которой соответствует ей в массиве? с else тоже не получается.

Comment: Что то я сомневаюсь, что у select есть value. У него что то типа selectedIndex есть, по которому находите нужный элемент среди option и берете его value. Да и массив imho не к чему, тем же option еще какой нибудь атрибут сделайте сразу со временем

Comment: @Mike, не сомневайтесь, есть value - https://jsfiddle.net/mok8aoLn/

Сергей74rus, вы хотите блокировать основываясь на значении времени?

Comment: просто сбрасывайте все выставленные стили и атрибуты

Comment: @Deonis, да все верно

Answer (score 1):

Вариант смотрите ниже, но не очень понятно, зачем вы каждой кнопке id задали и onclick.

```js
var dat = [{
  "Time": "09:00",
  "Proced": "Санникова Александра",
}, {
  "Time": "09:00",
  "Proced": "Лузанова Вера",
}, {
  "Time": "11:30",
  "Proced": "Праведникова Валентина"
}];

var buttons = $('.bb button');
$('#proced').on('change', function(){
  var name = $(this).val(),
      item = $(dat).filter(function(){
   return this.Proced === name;
      }).get(0);
  buttons.prop('disabled', false).css('color', '');
  if(typeof item === 'object' && item.hasOwnProperty('Time')) {
    buttons.filter(function(){
     return $.trim($(this).text()) === item.Time;
    }).prop('disabled', true).css('color', '#f00');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control input-sm" required name="Proced" id="proced" style="width:300px;">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Санникова Александра">Санникова Александра</option>
  <option value="Лузанова Вера">Лузанова Вера</option>
  <option value="Праведникова Валентина">Праведникова Валентина</option>
  <option value="Елена Чиркова">Елена Чиркова</option>
  <option value="Лебединская Ирина">Лебединская Ирина</option>

</select>
<section class="color-7" id="btn-click" style=" margin-top:45px ;">

  <p class="bb">


    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-09:00">09:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-09:30" onclick="">09:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-10:00" onclick="">10:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-10:30" onclick="">10:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-11:00" onclick="">11:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-11:30" onclick="">11:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-12:00" onclick="">12:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-12:30" onclick="">12:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-13:00" onclick="">13:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-13:30" onclick="">13:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-14:00" onclick="">14:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-14:30" onclick="">14:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-15:00" onclick="">15:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-15:30" onclick="">15:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-16:00" onclick="">16:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-16:30" onclick="">16:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-17:00" style="width:504px;" onclick="">17:00</button>

  </p>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант, но суть та же, в начале обработчика сбросить ранее установленные настройки

```
buttons.prop('disabled', false).css('background-color', '');
```

```js
var dat = [{
  "Time": "09:00",
  "Proced": "Санникова Александра",
}, {
  "Time": "09:00",
  "Proced": "Лузанова Вера",
}, {
  "Time": "11:30",
  "Proced": "Праведникова Валентина"
}];

var buttons = $('.btn-sample');

$("#proced").change(function() {

  buttons.prop('disabled', false).css('background-color', ''); //сбрасываем предыдущие настройки
  var val = $(this).val(); //получаем что выбрали сейчас

  for (var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++) {
    if (dat[i].Proced == val) { //если совпадает с сохраненным 
      $('#time-is-' + dat[i].Time.replace(':', '\\:')).prop('disabled', true).css('background-color', 'red'); //выставляем насйтроки конкретной кнопке
      break;
    }
  }
  /*
  //Данный код будет работать даже если в массиве может быть несколько элементов с одинаковым Proced
  dat.filter(function(el){return el.Proced == val}).forEach(function(el){
    $('#time-is-' + el.Time.replace(':', '\\:')).prop('disabled', true).css('background-color', 'red');
  });
  */

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control input-sm" required name="Proced" id="proced" style="width:300px;">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Санникова Александра">Санникова Александра</option>
  <option value="Лузанова Вера">Лузанова Вера</option>
  <option value="Праведникова Валентина">Праведникова Валентина</option>
  <option value="Елена Чиркова">Елена Чиркова</option>
  <option value="Лебединская Ирина">Лебединская Ирина</option>

</select>
<section class="color-7" id="btn-click" style=" margin-top:45px ;">

  <p class="bb">


    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-09:00">09:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-09:30" onclick="">09:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-10:00" onclick="">10:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-10:30" onclick="">10:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-11:00" onclick="">11:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-11:30" onclick="">11:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-12:00" onclick="">12:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-12:30" onclick="">12:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-13:00" onclick="">13:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-13:30" onclick="">13:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-14:00" onclick="">14:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-14:30" onclick="">14:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-15:00" onclick="">15:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-15:30" onclick="">15:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-16:00" onclick="">16:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-16:30" onclick="">16:30</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-17:00" style="width:504px;" onclick="">17:00</button>

  </p>

</section>
```